# How to use a Node.js module in CoffeScript in a JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I have been recommended this Node.js [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ger).

It is implemented in CoffeeScript, but I want to use it in my JavaScript project. Of course I will get an error message like this:

[image: node error screenshot]

What do I have to do to use the module in my project?

Comment: If you install `coffee-script` to your project, you can `require('coffee-script/register')` before `require('ger')` as noted in [CoffeeScript's Changelog](http://coffeescript.org/#1.7.0).

Comment: You should just require the compiled `ger.js`, not `ger.coffee`

Comment: @Bergi curious as to why, Jonathan Lonowski's solution does indeed work (and is incidentally what we use at work). Am I missing something?

Comment: @JaredSmith: If you're working in coffeescript, you'd register the coffee-script `require`-hook so that it transpiles all files on the fly. But if you're using javascript for your project, you'd usually use pre-transpiled library files instead of installing coffeescript and transpiling them yourself.

Comment: @Bergis comment is the one that is correct and should be used. Using the source directly should only be done if you're planning on developing for that library.

Comment: Link. It would be nice to have the name of the module though.